# How to fix form submission after using change or keyup

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using keyup to join two values from a wordpress form plugin (formidable pro) into another field in the same form, and then submitting that data however the form refreshes when clicking submit and doesn't submit the data unless I submit it again.

I have tried with change too and its the same result, here is the code I have used (both combine the values entered into the fields), it seems to be the form submission because if i remove the code the form submits. This is what I have tried:

```
$(".rafflePopup input").on("keyup", function(){
    $(".frm_forms input[type='hidden']").val($(".raffleEntryName input").val() + " - Apartment: " + $(".raffleEntryApartmentNumber input").val());
});
```

and also:

```
var value;
$('.raffleEntryName input').change(function() {
    value = $(this).val();
});
$('.raffleEntryApartmentNumber input').change(function() {
    value += " - Aprtment "+$(this).val();
    $(".frm_forms input[type='hidden']").val(value);
});
```

Can this be done in PHP before the form is submitted? or perhaps another way in jQuery.

I am expecting the form to submit and it to go to the thankyou page the form plugin has

Working updated code:

```
$(".rafflePopup input").on("keyup", function(){
    $(".frm_forms input#field_ayhi2").val($(".raffleEntryName input").val() + " - Apartment: " + $(".raffleEntryApartmentNumber input").val());
});
```

Comment: can you show us the form html code?

Comment: Yeah sure its here: https://pastebin.com/TmXbb1RF

Comment: I don't see any elements with classes `rafflePopup` or `frm_forms`

Comment: sorry the whole popup code is here: https://pastebin.com/wjxhHi4K

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`$(".rafflePopup input")` to `$("#form_raffle input")`

and

`$(".frm_forms input[type='hidden']")` to `$("#form_raffle input[type='hidden']")`

The problem is that the classes you are trying to access are on divs outside the form and the jquery selector doesn't find the associated input elements

Comment: Hi,
I figured it out, I found there was a lot of hidden fields and probably those were needed for something else so I referenced the ID of the particular field I wanted to populate and that fixed it, here is the updated code:

    $(".rafflePopup input").on("keyup", function(){
        $(".frm_forms input#field_ayhi2").val($(".raffleEntryName input").val() + " - Apartment: " + $(".raffleEntryApartmentNumber input").val());
    });